# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): MyPlugin does not have web implementation

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I made a custom Capacitor plugin for iOS, Android and Web (PWA) but when I open my capacitor based app in the browser I get the following error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): MyPlugin does not have web implementation.
```

So the problem seams to be Capacitor does not found the web implementation of the plugin.

Comment: refer this link,https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/749

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue running Capacitor v2.4.7. It appears to be caused by the destructuring of the `Plugins` object:

```
const {MyPlugin} = Plugins;
MyPlugin.myMethod(); // FAIL
```

I found that using the `Plugins` object directly avoided the error:

```
Plugins.MyPlugin.myMethod(); // OK
```

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/749#issuecomment-479781137

Answer (score 0):

To fix it within an Angular app you have to add the following line in your app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {MyPlugin} from "capacitor-myplugin";
import {registerWebPlugin} from "@capacitor/core";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            registerWebPlugin(MyPlugin);
        });
    }
}
```

[www.onexip.com](https://www.onexip.com)